# Script to convert ext4 filenames to NTFS

Tags: ntfs, filenames, ext4, special-characters, posix

ext4 allows certain chars in filenames which NTFS doesn't. Is there a script to replace those chars in filenames?

Comment: `pathchk` may help.  It doesn't do the conversion, but should tell you if a file needs converting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should replace all disallowed characters in filenames with underscores. Note that this may cause multiple files to be renamed to the same thing. For example, if you had two files called `file>/txt` and `file<.txt`, both will be renamed to `file_.txt`, and one will overwrite the other, deleting it.

`find /path/to/ntfs/mount/ -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's{[\\:*?"<>|]}{_}g'`

This command is valid for the perl version of rename, which is what Debian provides. Your distro may provide a version of rename with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: This syntax is only valid for [`perl-rename`](https://gist.github.com/raw/883553/01bb2c924a5724ea2b6804886c1a54329473fefa/prename), which ships as `rename` on Debian. Other distros come with a simpler `rename` from *util-linux*.

Comment: Also, 1) do not replace `/`, because this would affect legitimate path separators; 2) the `g` option is needed to match all characters, not just the first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

First I must note that NTFS supports the full [POSIX namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#namespaces) so file names on it can contain any characters except `/` and `'\0'` just like ext4. Only the Win32 namespace forbids some more characters and uses case-insensitive name lookups. In the past there were various [Unix subsystems in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1426824/241386) and nowadays there are WSL and WSL2 so you can freely store any kinds of Linux filenames on NTFS

So now in order to operate properly with apps that use the Win32 namespace you need to fix the names. But **it's a bad idea to replace all the forbidden characters with `_`**. There are so many good replacement characters in Unicode that you can use, for example just **convert the characters from the [half-width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) to their [full-width form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block))**. With `perl-rename` you can do this with the [`tr` command](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr)

```bash
find /mount/point -print0 | xargs -0 \
    rename 'use utf8; use open qw/:std :utf8/; tr#\\:*?"<>|#＼：＊？＂＜＞#'
```

If you want to limit to ASCII only then you can **find some character with the *similar meaning*** to replace, for example translating `"` to `'`

```bash
find /mount/point -print0 | xargs -0 rename 'tr#\\:*?"<>|#_\-._'"'"'[]!#'
```

Some more suggestions that you can choose for a better replacement string

- `\`: Reverse Solidus Operator ⧵ (U+29F5), Big Reverse Solidus ⧹ (U+29F9)
- `:`: see the [colon list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Computing): `ː˸∶︓﹕`
- `*`: choose one of the [various asterisk symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Encodings) like `*∗✱﹡＊✲⁎٭※✻✺`
- `?`: check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Computing): `¿⁇⍰❓❔︖﹖�`
- `"`: see [the list of quoting symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table), for example “
- `<`: `﹤≪⋖〈❬⟨〈`
- `>`: `﹥≫⋗〉❭⟩〉`
- `|`: check [vertical bar list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Unicode_code_points): `¦‖∣│।ǀ`